# How to Create a default Word Press password for new registered users

Tags: wordpress, change-password

I would like to know if it's possible to create a default password for newly registered users. In different words, disable and reconfigure the autogenerated password suggestion that is crazy long... and make it simpler for new users.

Thanks for your help

I tried to look into phpMyAdmin and Cpanel file manager, but I couldn't figure out which file would contain the default code that defines the basic pwd rules. I tried .htaccess, wp-signup, and setup-config but with no luck pinpointing the code.

Comment: This would obviously have some serious security implications. If people are getting confused, would it not work to just add some text to the registration form explaining more clearly that the user can type their own password into the box instead of using the auto-generated one?

Comment: Hi, @Shoelaced thanks for your feedback. I am aware of the security implications and I figured this might be why it's not a default feature. However, our goal is to provide access to an online course to specific users that we manually create. There is no way for any user to know other user login credentials. It's just annoying to copy the autogenerated password, as well as, copy the desired default password every time a new user is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "send mail to new user" option when creating the user, the new user NEVER has to use the "complicated" auto-generated password, but is asked to immediately set their own password when using the link in the email to connect to the site.